# Using python-openCV, is there a way to detect the corners of each polygon and print the name next to each polygon without using approxPolyDP()?

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection

**The project stages are as follows:**

- Triangle, square, rectangle, pentagon, hexagon, and circle geometric shapes are drawn on a piece of paper and the insides are painted.
- Some noise is added to the white parts of the paper, and then a photo is taken from the top of the paper while leaving half of the paper in the shade.
- The aim of the project is to have the contours drawn around the geometric shapes by ignoring the shadows and scratches on the photo and to print the name of that geometric shape without repeating it next to each shape.
  While doing this, one of the corner detection algorithms should be used. I think Shi-Tomasi Corner Detection tecnique can be used. Also, it is forbidden to use the "cv2.approxPolyDP()" command in this project.

The input image:
[geometric shapes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T02P.jpg)

I wrote some of the code, it detects the corners of shapes but i couldn't find how to count the corners of each shape individually. And also, i must add square-rectangle detection. Here's the code:

```
    import numpy as np
    import cv2

    img = cv2.resize(cv2.imread("shaded.jpeg"),(600,450))

    grayImage = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayImage,(11,11),0)
    
    kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9,9))
    opening = cv2.morphologyEx(blur, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
    closing = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
    corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(closing,22,0.01,10)
    corners = np.int0(corners)
    for i in corners:
        x, y = i.ravel()
        cv2.circle(img, [x, y], 3, (0,0,255), -1)
        num_corners = len(corners)
        if num_corners == 3:
            shape_name = "Triangle"
        elif num_corners == 4:
            shape_name = "Rectangle"
        elif num_corners == 5:
            shape_name = "Pentagon"
        elif num_corners == 6:
            shape_name = "Hexagon"
        else:
            shape_name = "Circle"

        cv2.putText(img, shape_name, (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0, 0, 0), 2)

    cv2.imshow("img", img)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The output:
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhqVZ.jpg)

Editted Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image = cv2.resize(cv2.imread('shaded.jpeg'), (600,450))
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5,5), 0)
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (9, 9))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(blurred, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
closing = cv2.morphologyEx(opening, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
 
binary = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(closing, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, 21, 10)
cv2.imshow("binary",binary)

contours, _ = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for i, contour in enumerate(contours):
    if cv2.contourArea(contour) < 2000:
        continue
    output = np.zeros_like(image)
    
    cv2.drawContours(output, [contour], 0, (255, 255, 255), cv2.FILLED)

    contoured = cv2.imshow("Contour " + str(i + 1), output)
    grayContoured = cv2.cvtColor(output, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    blurContoured = cv2.GaussianBlur(grayContoured, (5,5), 0)
    
    corners = cv2.goodFeaturesToTrack(blurContoured, 7, 0.01, 10)
    corners = np.int0(corners)
    for c in corners:
        x, y = c.ravel()
        cv2.circle(image, (x,y),3,(255,0,0),-1)
    
    num_corners = len(corners)
    cv2.putText(image, f'{num_corners}', (x-5,y-5), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,255), 2)
    if num_corners == 3:
        cv2.putText(image, "Triangle", (x-10,y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,255),2)
    elif num_corners == 4:
        x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(corners)
        aspectRatio = float(w)/h
        if aspectRatio >= 0.95 and aspectRatio <= 1.05:
            cv2.putText(image, "Square", (x-20, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,255),2)
        else:
            cv2.putText(image, "Rectangle", (x-10, y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,255),2)
    elif num_corners == 5:
        cv2.putText(image, "Pentagon", (x-10,y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,255),2)
    elif num_corners == 6:
        cv2.putText(image, "Hexagon", (x-10,y-10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,255),2)
    else:
        cv2.putText(image, "Circle", (x-10,y-20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.5, (0,0,255),2)

    cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.imshow("image",image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The new output:
[new output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3PLg.png)

Comment: Find contour. Then reduce the vertices using cv2.approxPolyDP().  See for example https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-detect-shapes-in-images-in-python-using-opencv/

Comment: I am currently doing an internship in image processing. This was how I first did it and I showed it to my mentor. Now she wants me to do this without using the cv2.approxPolyDP() command.

Comment: Get the contours. Loop over each one, one at a time. Then draw each one separately as white (filled?) on black background. Then get its contour and do your corner detection on that figure and count and store the values. Then repeat for each contour. Once done, draw each polygon or just its vertices on the original figure.

Comment: Thank you sir, I applied what you said. It helped me a lot. I added my editted code and new output to the bottom of the question. Now I just have one little problem to fix. When counting corner numbers, I defined the max corner value as 7 but it detects extra vertices in each shape.

Comment: Adjust parameters in goodFeaturesToTrack